# How to display the labels of the left and bottom axis to the right and top axis

Tags: wpf, vb.net, teechart

I want to display the labels at the left axis and bottom axis of a line graph to the right and top axis instead of the left and the bottom axis.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set series' horizontal and vertical axes:

```
line1.VertAxis = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.VerticalAxis.Right
line1.HorizAxis = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.HorizontalAxis.Top
```

You'll find more info on axis settings at tutorial 4, available at TeeChart's program group.